# access immediate children of a div

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, dom, cheerio

Below is my html code.

```
<div id="this">
    <a href="xxx"> xx</a>
    <a href="yy"> yy</a>
    <a href="zzz"> zzz</a>
    aaa
    <a href="bbb"> bbb</a>
    ccc
</div>
```

I have to get all children of `this` div, i.e [xx,yy,zzz,aaa,bbb,ccc]

But by using the below code i can get only [xx,yy,zzz,bbb]. How to access other 2[aaa,ccc]?

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

var $ = cheerio.load('<div id="this"> <a href="xxx"> xx</a> <a href="yy"> yy</a> <a href="zzz"> zzz</a> aaa <a href="bbb"> bbb</a> ccc </div>')

$('div#this').children().each(function(i, child){
    console.log($(this).text())
})
```

Comment: *Side note* started with `<div>` closed with `</td>` ?

Comment: edited my actual code, forgot to change `</td>` in the last

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Element` and `Text` share the same parent `Node` in the inheritance chain (DOM4 adds `CharacterData`).  `Element.childNodes` is `NodeList` and `Element.children` is `HTMLCollection` which is a collection of elements. `jQuery.children` returns an elements collection without `Text`s. You can access the raw DOM element to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `[aaa,ccc]` are text nodes, which are not considered as children, what you could do is use `contents` instead of `children`. Bear in mind that this will returns comment nodes as well

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

var $ = cheerio.load('<div id="this"> <a href="xxx"> xx</a> <a href="yy"> yy</a> <a href="zzz"> zzz</a> aaa <a href="bbb"> bbb</a> ccc </div>')

$('div#this').contents().each(function(i, child){
   console.log($(this).text())
})
```